# react-spring/three not working for mesh color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I am trying to add a color transition for my mesh but am unable to do so with `react-spring`

`Scene.js`

```js
import { useSpring, animated } from '@react-spring/three'

const Cell = () => {
  const [hovered, hover] = useState(false);
  const springs = useSpring({ color: hovered ? 'hotpink' : 'orange'})

  <animated.mesh
   onPointerEnter={(e) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        hover(true);
      }}
      onPointerLeave={(e) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        hover(false);
      }}
   >
    <planeGeometry args={[1, 1, 1]} />
    <meshBasicMaterial color={springs.color} />
  </animated.mesh
}
```

This just leaves my mesh with a white/grey color.

In the example provided [here](https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/tutorials/using-with-react-spring) they used it in a similar way and I am unsure why it does not work. I have tested this by changed `scale` on the mesh itself and it worked then.

Answer (score 0):

SpringValues can only be applied to `animated` components. You have three components there, `mesh`, `planeGeometry` and `meshBasicMaterial`. You've animated `mesh` but you're not applying SpringValues to it so that's redundant.

Because you want the `meshBasicMaterial` to handle the SpringValue you should write it like so:

```js
const Cell = () => {
  const [hovered, hover] = useState(false);
  const springs = useSpring({ color: hovered ? 'hotpink' : 'orange'})

  return <mesh
   onPointerEnter={(e) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        hover(true);
      }}
      onPointerLeave={(e) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        hover(false);
      }}
   >
    <planeGeometry args={[1, 1, 1]} />
    <animated.meshBasicMaterial color={springs.color} />
  </animated.mesh
}
```

You can see this working here – https://codesandbox.io/s/react-spring-forked-6qgre?file=/src/App.js